# Conditionally displaying a value in upper case

Tags: sql, t-sql, uppercase

I have a very simple query but I need to have it so that if `Conditional` is less than two then `Title` should be displayed as all CAPS

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title, COUNT(Title) AS NumberOfTitles
FROM Table 
WHERE Conditional < 3
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Title
```

I've tried `CASE` etc. but can seem to get it to work

I also need to set Title to 'MAIN' if conditional = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
case when conditional = 1 then 'MAIN'
when conditional <> 1 and conditional < 2 then UPPER(Title)
else Title end as Title
, COUNT(Title) AS NumberOfTitles
FROM Table 
GROUP BY case when conditional = 1 then 'MAIN'
         when conditional <> 1 and conditional < 2 then UPPER(Title)
         else Title end
ORDER BY case when conditional = 1 then 'MAIN'
         when conditional <> 1 and conditional < 2 then UPPER(Title)
         else Title end
```

You can try this with a `case` statement.

Comment: I also need to change Title to "MAIN" if conditional is 1, can i use the same case or do I need a secondary one?

Comment: see the modified version.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the logic in a common table expression to avoid repeating it in the `group by` and `order by` clauses:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       CASE WHEN conditional < 2 THEN UPPER(Title)
            ELSE Title 
       END AS Title
    FROM Table 
) 

SELECT Title, COUNT(Title) AS NumberOfTitles
FROM cte
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Title;
```